# Repeating a vertical line of background

Tags: css, background, background-image, gradient

I have this background that isn't a solid colour (it's basically an image), the pattern and gradient changes as the page goes down. I want to keep the gradient and make it infinite.

I was thinking of taking the last 1-2px on the sides and just replicating it left and right. it works in Photoshop but how can i do in in html/css ? [Here how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNen9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've got it but I think this gonna work.
HTML:

```
<body>
   <main>
   </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-image: (your-image);
 background-size: fixed;
 }

main {
 height: 50vh; //optional
 width: 70%;
}
```